# How to make periodic api calls even when my web app is closed in chrome

Tags: javascript, web, browser, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

My usecase:
I have to make rest api call for every 2 hours of interval even my web application is not running in chrome.

I have tried with periodic sync feature in service worker for my web application.
Currently periodic sync in chrome will dispatch events based on many criteria ( power save mode, presence for network, site engagement score...). Also with min interval of 12 hours to dispatch event.

Is there any way to make periodic api calls even web app is not running (other than periodic background sync) ?.

Comment: look into service workers. they are complicated, be warned.

Comment: There is probably no other way. But maybe there is a solution not involving calling an API every 2 hours. What is your use case?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I have to make API call to connect with server for 2 hours of interval for check any update for the user. but curious to know how we can achieve with not involving API calls. can you explain?